# how to change domain on otrs system

Tags: otrs

I've installed `otrs 6` on a system with `Centos 7` and with name `test.domain.local`. Now I've changed the name into `ticket.domain.com`. I've changed `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` and then I reboot the server. Now when I try to access to the site http://ticket.domain.com/otrs/index.pl it shows:

> Message: Access denied for user 'otrs'@'ticket.domain.com' (using password: YES)

I have already changed in the `/opt/otrs/Kernel/Config/Files/ZZZAAuto.pm`.

Can anyone help me ??